# Redux Form - populating initial values

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-form

I am trying to populate a form with initial data however I am unsure of the syntax for this functionality and how it's suppose to be applied.  initially the form I am using is a component that I also use to create a client. I am trying to reuse this form as the form for editing a client. It has two functions.

As per suggestions in Redux I have a this as a component and I also have a container.

Now, using the redux tool in Chrome I can look at the state and its clear the action has added an "editClient" entry with data so I do have the data. Its called "editClient" in the state.

My problem is that I do not know how to use this to set these state values as initial values. I have looked carefully at the docs but I am confused as to the way it should be stuctured.

Here is my client form in its entirety:

```
    import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
    import { Field, reduxForm, FormSection } from 'redux-form'
    import { connect } from 'react-redux'
    import { Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap'
    import { Button, Glyphicon, Panel } from 'react-bootstrap'
    import Moment from 'moment'
    import Address from '../../address/addressContainer'
    import FormField from '../../formComponents/formField'
    import CheckboxField from '../../formComponents/checkboxField'
    import TextField from '../../formComponents/textField'
    import StaticText from '../../formComponents/staticText'
    import TextAreaField from '../../formComponents/textAreaField'
    import DateField from '../../formComponents/datefield'

    import reducer from '../edit/reducer'

    export const CLIENT_FORM_NAME = 'Client'

    const required = value => (value ? undefined : 'Required')
    const maxLength = max => value =>
      value && value.length > max ? `Must be ${max} characters or less` : undefined
    const number = value =>
      value && isNaN(Number(value)) ? 'Must be a number' : undefined
    const minValue = min => value =>
      value && value < min ? `Must be at least ${min}` : undefined
    const email = value =>
      value && !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(value)
        ? 'Invalid email address'
        : undefined
    const tooOld = value =>
      value && value > 65 ? 'You might be too old for this' : undefined
    const aol = value =>
      value && /.+@aol\.com/.test(value)
        ? 'Really? You still use AOL for your email?'
        : undefined

    const normalizeMobilePhone = value => {
      if (!value) {
        return value
      }

      const onlyNums = value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
      if (onlyNums.length <= 4) {
        return onlyNums
      }
      if (onlyNums.length <= 8) {
        return `${onlyNums.slice(0, 4)} ${onlyNums.slice(4)}`
      }
      return `${onlyNums.slice(0, 4)} ${onlyNums.slice(4, 7)} ${onlyNums.slice(7, 10)}`
    }

    export const Client = (props) => {
      const { 
        handleSubmit,
        companyValue,
        isWarrantyCompanyValue,
        isEditMode } = props

      const { reset } = props

      return (
        <Row>
          <Col md={12}>
            <h2><Glyphicon glyph="edit" /> {isEditMode ? 'Edit' : 'New'} Client</h2>
            <hr />
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="form-horizontal">
              {isEditMode && (
                <Panel header={<h3>Client - Basic Details</h3>}>
                  <Row>
                    <Field component={StaticText}
                      name="clientNo"
                      id="clientNo"
                      label="Client No."
                      fieldCols={4}
                      labelCols={4}
                      controlCols={8}
                    />

                    <Field component={StaticText}
                      name="dateCreated"
                      id="dateCreated"
                      label="Date Created."
                      fieldCols={4}
                      labelCols={4}
                      controlCols={8}
                    />

                    <Field component={StaticText}
                      name="userName"
                      id="userName"
                      label="Created By."
                      fieldCols={4}
                      labelCols={4}
                      controlCols={8}
                    />
                  </Row>

                  <Row>
                    <Field
                      component={props => {
                        return (
                          <StaticText {...props}>
                            <p
                              className="form-control-static"
                            >
                              <Glyphicon glyph={props.input.value ? 'ok' : 'remove'} />
                              {' '}{props.input.value ? 'Has jobs attached' : 'No jobs attached'}
                            </p>
                          </StaticText>
                        )
                      }}
                      name="activity"
                      id="activity"
                      label="Activity"
                      fieldCols={4}
                      labelCols={4}
                      controlCols={8}
                    />

                    <Field component={CheckboxField}
                      name="active"
                      id="active"
                      label="De-Activate"
                      checkboxLabel="De activate this client"
                      fieldCols={4}
                      labelCols={4}
                      controlCols={8}
                    />
                  </Row>
                </Panel>
              )}

              <Panel header={<h3>Client - CompanyDetails</h3>}>

                <Row>
                  <Field component={CheckboxField}
                    id="company"
                    name="company"
                    label="Company?"
                    checkboxLabel="Client represents a company"
                    fieldCols={6}
                    labelCols={3}
                    controlCols={9}
                  />
                </Row>
                {companyValue && (
                  <div>
                    <Row>
                      <Field component={TextField}
                        name="companyName"
                        id="companyName"
                        type="text"
                        label="Company Name"
                        placeholder="Enter company name..."
                        fieldCols={6}
                        labelCols={3}
                        controlCols={9}
                      />

                      <Field component={TextField}
                        name="abn"
                        id="abn"
                        type="text"
                        label="ABN."
                        fieldCols={6}
                        labelCols={3}
                        controlCols={5}
                      />
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                      <Field component={CheckboxField}
                        id="isWarrantyCompany"
                        name="isWarrantyCompany"
                        label="Warranty Company?"
                        checkboxLabel="Client represents a warranty company"
                        fieldCols={6}
                        labelCols={3}
                        controlCols={9}
                      />
                      {isWarrantyCompanyValue && (
                        <Field component={CheckboxField}
                          id="requiresPartsPayment"
                          name="requiresPartsPayment"
                          label="Requires Parts Payment?"
                          checkboxLabel="We pay for parts"
                          fieldCols={6}
                          labelCols={3}
                          controlCols={9}
                        />
                      )}
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                      <Field component={TextField}
                        name="companyEmail"
                        id="companyEmail"
                        type="email"
                        label="Spare Parts Email."
                        placeholder="Enter spare parts email..."
                        fieldCols={6}
                        labelCols={3}
                        controlCols={9}
                      />
                    </Row>
                  </div>
                )}
              </Panel>

              <Panel header={<h3>Client - {companyValue ? 'Company Contact' : 'Personal'} Details</h3>}>

                <Row>
                  <Field component={TextField}
                    name="clientFirstName"
                    id="clientFirstName"
                    type="text"
                    label="First Name."
                    placeholder="Enter first name..."
                    fieldCols={6}
                    labelCols={3}
                    controlCols={9}
                    validate={[required]}
                  />

                  <Field component={TextField}
                    name="clientLastName"
                    id="clientLastName"
                    type="text"
                    label="Last Name."
                    placeholder="Enter last name..."
                    fieldCols={6}
                    labelCols={3}
                    controlCols={9}
                  />
                </Row>

                <Row>
                  <Field component={TextField}
                    name="mobilePhone"
                    id="mobilePhone"
                    type="text"
                    label="Mobile No."
                    placeholder="Enter mobile No..."
                    fieldCols={6}
                    labelCols={3}
                    controlCols={5}
                    normalize={normalizeMobilePhone}
                  />

                  <Field component={TextField}
                    name="phone"
                    id="phone"
                    type="text"
                    label="Phone No."
                    placeholder="Enter phone No..."
                    fieldCols={6}
                    labelCols={3}
                    controlCols={5}
                  />
                </Row>

                <Row>
                  <Field component={TextField}
                    name="email"
                    id="email"
                    type="email"
                    label="Email."
                    placeholder="Enter email address..."
                    fieldCols={6}
                    labelCols={3}
                    controlCols={9}
                  />
                </Row>
              </Panel>

              <FormSection name="Address">
                <Address />
              </FormSection>

              <Panel header={<h3>Notes</h3>}>
                <Row>
                  <Field component={TextAreaField}
                    id="notes"
                    name="notes"
                    label="Notes."
                    placeholder="Enter notes here..."
                    fieldCols={12}
                    labelCols={1}
                    controlCols={11}
                  />
                </Row>
              </Panel>

              <Panel header={<h3>Client - Bank Details</h3>}>
                <Row>
                  <Field component={TextField}
                    name="bankName"
                    id="bankName"
                    type="text"
                    label="Bank Name."
                    placeholder="Enter bank name..."
                    fieldCols={4}
                    labelCols={4}
                    controlCols={8}
                  />

                  <Field component={TextField}
                    name="bsb"
                    id="bsb"
                    type="text"
                    label="BSB No."
                    placeholder="Enter BSB No..."
                    fieldCols={4}
                    labelCols={4}
                    controlCols={8}
                  />


                  <Field component={TextField}
                    name="account"
                    id="account"
                    type="text"
                    label="Account No."
                    placeholder="Enter Account No..."
                    fieldCols={4}
                    labelCols={4}
                    controlCols={8}
                  />
                </Row>
              </Panel>

              <div className="panel-body">
                <Row>
                  <Col xs={4}>
                    <Row>
                      <Col xs={8} xsOffset={4}>
                        <Button bsStyle="primary" type="submit" bsSize="small">
                          <Glyphicon glyph="ok" /> Submit
                        </Button>
                        {' '}
                        <Button type="reset" bsSize="small" onClick={reset}>
                          <Glyphicon glyph="ban-circle" /> Clear
                        </Button>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </div>
            </form>
          </Col>
        </Row >
      )
    }

    let ClientForm = reduxForm({
      form: CLIENT_FORM_NAME,

    })(Client)

    ClientForm = connect(
      state => ({
        initialValues: state.editClient // pull initial values from client reducer
      }),
      { reducer } // bind client loading action creator
    )(Client)

    export default ClientForm
```

I have added the following at the bottom as per the redux form example:

```
    ClientForm = connect(
    state => ({
      initialValues: state.editClient // pull initial values from client reducer
    }),
    { reducer } // bind client loading action creator
  )(Client)
```

...wnd when I save it I get the following error.

> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Field must be inside a component decorated with reduxForm()

I believe I have not understood how to set the initial values.

Where have I gone wrong and what I need to do to make this take the state values and load them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter for the function that `connect` returns should be `ClientForm` instead of `Client`. Try this:

```
ClientForm = connect(
  state => ({
    initialValues: state.editClient // pull initial values from client reducer
  }),
  { reducer } // bind client loading action creator
)(ClientForm)
```

Comment: Its not erroring anymore which is great however its still not loading the initial values. What am I missing?

Comment: Should just work, can you try to hardcode `initialValues` and check if that works? `initialValues: { account: 'foo', bsb: 'bar', ... }`